# Alert dialog button has different colorset

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, androidx, material-components-android

[image]

hello, I have an alert dialog. the buttons are purple. yes I can change the color of the text inside using:

```
          alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).
                    setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

however when they are touched, there is a purple hue that forms. 
I want the hue to be blue like the main accent of my app and the text to be black.

this is my alert style:

```
<style name="MyCustomAlert2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/materialBlue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/custom_alert2</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/materialBlue</item>
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

note: none of the colors linked above are purple.

thanks for the help

Comment: You have to pass the theme into the AlertDialog

Comment: Check in color file is any purple colour define.

Comment: Something like this: `AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(this, R.style.MyCustomAlert2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use new the[`androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.html) and the [**Material** components for android library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Just use something like:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("...")
            .setMessage("....")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null)
            .show();
```

Then you can customize the style with something like:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog</item>
  </style>
```

and here you can change each button:

```
  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/selector_bt</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

You can set the style globally in your app theme using:

```
<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
```

or you can use the constructor:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,
          R.style.MyThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
```